# Is there a simple proof of the theorem "If $H \subset \mathbb{Z}^n$ is a subgroup then $H \cong \mathbb{Z}^k$ for some $k$ with $0 \leq k \leq n$."?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, free-abelian-group

The title really explains it, the proof in my text uses induction and I understand up to:

(For $m=0$): Since $H \subset \mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$ is a subgroup, so is $\pi(H) \subset \mathbb{Z}$. Hence $\pi(H) = m\mathbb{Z}$ for some $m \geq 0$. If $m=0$, then $\pi(H) = (0)$ so $H \subset ker(\pi)$ which implies $\mathbb{Z}^k \cong H \cap ker(\pi) = H$.

(Where we defined $\pi: \mathbb{Z}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ by $\pi(m_{1},...,m_{n+1}) = m_{n+1}$.)

I understood up to there but then it continues:

From now on assume $m\neq 0$. Since $m \in m\mathbb{Z} = \pi(H)$, we have $h_{k+1} \in H$ with  $\pi(h_{k+1}) = m$. Take $h_{1},...,h_{k} \in H \cap ker(\pi)$ the images of $(1,0,...,0),...,(0,...0,1)$ under a chosen isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}^k \cong H \cap ker(\pi)$. We will show that $\psi : \mathbb{Z}^{k+1} \rightarrow H$ defined by $\psi(m_{1},...,m_{k+1}) = m_{1}h_{1}+...+m_{k+1}h_{k+1}$ is an isomorphism.

And I'm just completely lost. I vaguely get the theorem intuitively and I know we have to use the fact that $H \cong \mathbb{Z}^k \iff H$ is a free abelian group. Does anyone have a straightforward proof?

Comment: I am not aware of any... However, what helps me understand this proof is to look at $\mathbb Z^{n+1}\cong\mathbb Z^n\times\mathbb Z$ and "see" $\mathbb Z^n$ and $\mathbb Z$ actually as *subgroups* of $\mathbb Z^{n+1}$. The former is what they call $\ker(\pi)$. The picture in my head is a familiar - a vector space (of dimension $n+1$) as a direct sum of two subspaces (of dimensions $n$ and $1$, respectively). Now, the proof starts with: either $H\subset \mathbb Z^n$ or not. If yes, the inductive hypothesis finishes the proof. Otherwise, apply the inductive hypothesis to $H\cap\mathbb Z^n$ etc.

Comment: The analogy with vector spaces is useful - later on, you will learn that Abelian groups are just *modules* over $\mathbb Z$, which is a fancy way to say that they are almost like vector spaces, except the scalars come not from a field, but from a ring (in this case $\mathbb Z$). Hope this helps.